# How to change the colour of Sticky Notes in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, colors, sticky-notes

I know the usual method to change the colour to some other prredefined colour as given below:
[image: Sticky Note]
The given colours are there for a long time and I get bored using only these colours.
Also, I am using a dark theme and I configured most of the monitor elements to use a dark colour, but I cannot change the colour of sticky notes to a dark colour with light colour text.

Is there any hack to do it?

Or any formal way?

Comment: You can change Font but I have found no way to add colors to the note itself. You would need to use a third party notes software that has more color selections  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJEFg7OE7Os

Comment: @Moab Thnks for the reply, but I shall wait before going with third party.

Comment: @Moab Do you know how to change the font colour?